# Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:8080 but can't find PORT?

Tags: express, cmd, port, port80

I have this code currently:

```
var express    = require('express');        
var app        = express();                 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var sessionManager = require("./SessionRaterBL");
sessionManager.CreateTestData();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;       


var router = express.Router();              
var sessionRouter = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req, res) {  
res.json({ message: 'API Session Rater Backend' });  
});

sessionRouter.get("/",function(req,res){
res.json(sessionManager.GetSessions())     
});

sessionRouter.get("/:id",function(req,res){
    var session;
    try{
        session = sessionManager.GetSession(req.param.id);
        res.json(session);
    }catch(ex){
        res.status(404).send(ex);
    } 
});


app.use('/api', router);
app.use('/api/sessions',sessionRouter);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

When executing the program I get the above named error.

So I did a netstat -anb I get this:  [all ports](https://pastebin.com/eqfkmBQY)

So I tried finding the PORT 8080 or 80 but I just could not find it.
If I execute my Node.js Program with a different Port for example: 1000. It works!.

Comment: @MikaS No. Now I did and I get this:  Es konnten keine Besitzerinformationen abgerufen werden.
  TCP    [::]:8080

Comment: @MikaS C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -ano | find "8080"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              ABHÖREN         4
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 ABHÖREN         4

Comment: @MikaS well I have PL/SQL open but when  I close it it still wont work

Comment: You could try using [tcpview](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) to find the process.

Comment: @MikaS there is no PID with 8080. But only two local ports: both of them are the process "system" with PID 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.

What I did was I changed the port of the default website in the IIS-Manager from 8080 to 80 and than I reseted the IIS-Manager. It worked!

Answer (score 7):

live-serve --port=8090 
simple and easy

Comment: I tried it with any possible port but the error is not gone

Answer (score 3):

```
live-server --port=8090
```

simple and easy

Answer (score 0):

Just run

`serve --port=80`

where 80 is the port you want to launch the program.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the port number -> port=8090